# Circle touching three circles

Tags: circles

For some tasks to prove I need to know if there always exists a circle which is tangent to three given circles but contains none of the three given circles. It is ensured to have middle radius smaller than left and right radius. I know there is a problem named Apollonius' Problem which is closely related to it. I searched a bit about this on internet. But couldn't find straight answer to my question. That's why I am asking here. It'd be great if any one could provide the link of proof in favor of or contrary to the above statement.

Comment: if you have three circles with centers on a straight line, the outer two have the same radius but the middle one has a larger radius, you cannot do it: all six mutual tangent circles contain two or three of the circles.

Comment: I see. There really are the full eight solutions. The final two have just the central circle inside.

Comment: @Will, oh, I forgot to mention something. It is ensured to have middle radius smaller than left and right radius. Is it possible then in all cases?

Answer (score 2):

Not my best artwork, anyway, three original circles in [deep purple](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUwEIt9ez7M) [with shading](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4QBhC1uCP4); two light blue mutual tangent circles, two light green, four orange. Should anyone have trouble seeing which colors go where, both green and blue are left-right symmetric, all three circles are inside the light blue circles/arcs, only the large central purple circle is inside the two green circles.

[image]

Comment: Is that link promoting "deep purple" music? Then maybe I should flag for spam... :)

Comment: It's not spam if it's good...right?

Comment: @TMM, you're missing the point: it's *subliminal*

Comment: For it to be sub[l](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subliminal_stimuli)iminal you really have to hide it better... Now it's just spam in plain sight!

Comment: @TMM Yeah, the trouble is it changes the characters in the link to blue. Quite liminal. Anyway, first i was going to write dark purple (note the colors here are not such good approximations to the original colors), then I thought no, deep purple, then i looked for youtube songs.

Comment: "Should anyone have trouble seeing which colors go where, ..." ...and "deep purple" goes to YouTube :)

Comment: @TMM, "with shading" goes somewhere slightly different on youtube. I really thought they had more songs that stuck in my mind, I guess I am remembering parts of songs by quite a number of different bands. Some commonality, though, White Room and Sunshine of Your Love were by Cream, and the bands knew each other.

Comment: What if both side circles have larger radius than the middle one?